# What is meaning of "FCM Automatic/Dynamic Resource Adjustment"?

Tags: db2, db2-luw

Few times per day on Db2 v11.5.8.0 Linux/x86_64 on several databases the following warning appears in db2diag.log file:

```
2023-03-14-08.00.39.289489+060 I4031117E469          LEVEL: Warning
PID     : 3684                 TID : 139752049207040 PROC : db2sysc 0
INSTANCE: prod034              NODE : 000
HOSTNAME: some_host
EDUID   : 20                   EDUNAME: db2tcpcm 0
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, fast comm manager, sqkfDynamicResourceMgr::AdjustResources,
          probe:175
MESSAGE : FCM Automatic/Dynamic Resource Adjustment (Session): 128 successfully
          allocated. New total is 384
```

1. What is this "FCM Automatic" warning all about?
2. Why is it "LEVEL = Warning" if there "MESSAGE = successfully"?
3. Is there some setting I can change to prevent this warnings in future?

Comment: Are any of your db2-instances partitioned (dpf), or do they purescale?  Is your configuration at default 'fcm_num_buffer' = automatic?  If auto tuning is active, Db2 will reduce the memory for certain buffers when they are not  being used.  Db2 chooses to log some messages according to the diaglevel.  You can change the dbm cfg parameter DIAGLEVEL to reduce logging of diagnostic messages.  Study the Db2-docs for more information about the fast communication manager.

Comment: Thanks for reply. DBM CFG 'fcm_num_buffer' is set to AUTOMATIC and DBM CFG "diaglevel" is set to 3. Both are default settings. No this databases are not partitioned or purescale. Just ordinary single database per instance.

Answer (score 1):

Study the DB2-docs for more information about the Fast communication Manager ([FCM](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=unix-fast-communications-manager)). In particular, on that page study all of the related references pages that describe what can be tuned.

As your instances are neither partitioned nor purescale, and you are using default settings  it's likely that the default number of buffers that the Db2-instance allocates for the FCM is 'surplus to requirements' and will be reduced so that that memory is made available for other Db2 purposes.

Db2 chooses to log some automated adjustments in db2diag according to the DIAGLEVEL, which in your instances is 3 the default. You can ignore such warning messages, they are relevant to certain problem determination efforts for specific problems. You can also change the DIAGLEVEL value e.g. to 2 or 1 but it is wise to leave it alone especially if you are learning Db2 or if you are bedding-in a new application.

It is normal for new Db2-versions (and sometimes new Db2-fixpacks) to have additional levers (config parameters). IBM describes these in the Knowledge Centre. The DBA should get familiar with such changes, via the "what's new" parts of the Knowledge-Centre for the new version and/or new fixpack .

Additionally Db2 often has defects that get addressed by later fixpacks so always ensure after migration that you are migrating to the latest available fixpack.

Comment: Few days ago I have migrated few of the v11.1 databases to v11.5 and there were no warning like this in v11.1. Is this something new to v11.5? I see on v11.1 there was only DBM CFG parameter FCM_BUFFER_SIZE, but now in v11.5 there are: FCM_NUM_BUFFERS = AUTOMATIC(4096), FCM_BUFFER_SIZE = 32768, FCM_NUM_CHANNELS = AUTOMATIC(2048), FCM_PARALLELISM = AUTOMATIC(12)

Comment: All these parameters exist in v11.1 and in many older db2 versions. You may check it switching versions at the following doc links. [FCM_NUM_BUFFERS](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.config.doc/doc/r0000118.html), [FCM_NUM_CHANNELS](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.config.doc/doc/r0022604.html), [FCM_PARALLELISM](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.config.doc/doc/r0060554.html)